# rails render json add custom attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method call:

```
def group
    render :json => Group.find(params[:id])
end
```

Which renders:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Name Here",
  description: "Description Here",
  created_at: "2014-11-24T19:10:53.609Z",
  updated_at: "2014-11-24T19:10:53.609Z"
}
```

I would like to also append a custom attribute the the group model being rendered. For example I'd like the group JSON to include an attribute `message : "Hello World"`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding a method to my model called `message` that returns a string and then calling,

```
render :json => Group.find(params[:id]), :methods => :message
```

did the trick.